# Seeking an explanation of the hadith: "Fear the prayer of the oppressed, even if he is a disbeliever, for there is no barrier (between it and Allah).”

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Please can anyone explain the following hadith?

> The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Fear the prayer of the oppressed, even if he is a disbeliever, for there is no barrier (between it and Allah).”

(It is referenced on e.g. [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/177561).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are referring to a special version of this sahih hadith ([al-Bukahri](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/46/9), and a longer Version for example in [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/29)) on the supplication/curse of an oppressed دعوة المظلوم. Note the addition of "e*ven if he is a disbeliever*" doesn't have enough support to be qualifeid as sahih, so it is in best case considered as a "hassan" hadith.

I think the longer Version which is also in sahih al-Bukahri, Jami' [at-Tirmdihi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/7/9), sunan [abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/9/29), sunan [an-Nasai](http://sunnah.com/urn/1125310), sunan [ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/8/1). Gives a hint on how this is to be understood we should not oppress others as Allah hates the oppressor and oppression (see for example [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/muslim/45/74)) as quoted in [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/muslim/45/70) qodsi. If an oppressed person asks Allah doing supplication or cursing somebody then they will reach Allah, even if this person maybe a sinner or a non-believer (as stated clearly in the hadith in Musnad Ahmad on the authority of Anas " دعوة المظلوم وإن كان كافرا ليس دونها حجاب" which you -apparently- are referring to) or somebody who eats haram as stated in [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/urn/639830).

The -apparently contradicting- quote from [13:14](http://legacy.quran.com/13/14) and [40:50](http://legacy.quran.com/40/50) saying:

> ...  And the supplication of the disbelievers is not but in error [i.e. futility].

is referring to the supplication of the non-believers asking Allah to not let them enter jahanam. It doesn't cover any other kind of supplication, which is perfectly permissible for them (see for example [this hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1372), where a Jewish woman made a supplication for 'Aisha).

On the importance and acceptance of the suplication of an oppressed see also this hadith which is in jami' [at-Tirmdihi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/79), sunan abi Dawod and sunan ibn Majah.

And Allah knows best!